# Update join on postgresql - Relation does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using DBeaver as a DBMS, and trying to update a table based on a join:

```
update cbn
set cbn.pathways = pc.pathways
from public.conformed_block_names cbn
left join pathwayslist_csv pc
    on pc.block_code = cbn.block_code
where pc.block_code is not null
```

So what i'm trying to do is update the table conformed_block_names based on a join between this table and table pathwayslist_csv

However, I keep getting the error "ERROR: relation "cbn" does not exist"

I've tried restructuring the update in many different ways, but I'm not getting anywhere with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE conformed_block_names
SET pathways = pc.pathways
FROM pathwayslist_csv pc
WHERE pc.block_code = conformed_block_names.block_code
    AND pc.block_code IS NOT null;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! This one gives me a "column pc.block_code does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "pc.block_code"." error

Comment: You should check the schema of that table with `\d pathwayslist_csv`. Maybe it has double quotes in the name I am not sure

Comment: Managed to get it working with pc."block_code"! Thanks a lot for the help, I've spent the last 3h trying to get this stupid join update to work :-)